# How to get Hindi Keyboard/translate into hindi text programatically in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in Android Tablet , i created below  query to get hindi text dynamically but no response.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006418/how-to-dynamically-convert-and-show-data-in-hindi-in-android

If it's not possible at least guide me how can i programatically get Hindi Virtual Keboard in my Bee tel Tablet.
Or else i need to translate English into hindi dynamically for that i already know if i use **Google Translator API** we can do this but in my case most of the time my application will work **without any internet/network** so in that case i can't use google translator so can any one tell me any other alternatives i have....

Please give me reply,for every valuable answer i will give Kudos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really serious about this, use the [transliteration api from Google](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html).

It's paid, it used to be free.

I think you should go and [pester Google here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7619).

---

Meanwhile can you try using [icu4j](http://userguide.icu-project.org/icufaq/icu4j-faq#TOC-What-version-of-Java-is-required-fo) ?, [it seems to support Devanagari transliteration](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general)

[icu4j transliteration API](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Transliterator.html#transliterate%28java.lang.String%29)

```
myTrans = new Transliterator("Latin-Devanagari", null);
String output = myTrans.transliterate(myString);
```

Comment: Hi Reno thanks for update Goole Translation api will only work if we have internet but my app needs to work in without internet cases also means for rural areas...and for icu4j any examples in android

Comment: Updated my answer, please note that I haven't tested it. You have to study how to use the api before you get the output that is satisfactory.

Comment: I used below code but nothing is happen                                                    Transliterator myTrans = Transliterator.getInstance("Latin-Devanagari");
   String output = myTrans.transliterate("Raja Sekhar");

Comment: call `getAvailableIDs()` to see if it is supported first.