# how to set hindi font in a webView in android

Tags: android

I want change the default font of webview to a custom font. I'm using webview in my app for Android.

I tried getting an instance of custom typeface by placing my custom font in assets. But still couldn't set webview's default font to my font.

This is what I tried:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Hindi/MyHTMLinHindi.html");
```

and in css file I tried:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:Mangal;
  src: url("file:///android_asset/Fonts/mangal.ttf")
  }
  body {
  font-family:Mangal;
  }
```

Please Suggest me any Way....
Thanx in advance..

Comment: Check this,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033583/how-to-get-hindi-keyboard-translate-into-hindi-text-programatically-in-android

this may help you.