# Android English to hindi translator

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which is both in Hindi and English.I have an activity in which i bind edit text's with some values.
When I am selecting English language everything goes perfectly but when the user selects the Hindi language,I want is to bind edit text's value in Hindi.
This is my part of code

```
  if(language.equals("1"))
    {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(AddNewAddress.this.getAssets(),"fonts/Krishna.ttf");
        mySpinner.setTypeface(font);
        area.setTypeface(font);
        mySpinner.setText(cityname);
        area.setText(areaname);
    }
```

I have downloaded this Krishna font file from google and used it as mentioned above.But the problem is that it does not  convert english text into hindi properly.
I have attached the screenshot

[image]

In the Screenshot I have Sector 18 and Satna as English values but the screenshot in hindi language does not convert these texts into hindi properly

[image]

Guys suggest me where I am wrong

Comment: Refer android localization. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: but this does not convert the dynamic text fields,,I have used this but it only works for static textvalues

Comment: use google traslator api but its paid

Comment: From the screenshots it looks like these are static values, anyway I don't know any methods for dynamic translation. English - Hindi translation may not be 100% accurate by using any APIs. Better choice would be using localization if you can.

Comment: I have used loaclization but in vain @shine_joseph

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html

Comment: In system setting under keyboard & input section, select current keyboard as Google Hindi input.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to add another values folder named as values-hi. 
You have to add strings.xml in that folder. 
 Make sure that 'strings.xml' in both folder should be same.
 And add your text of Edittext in new strings.xml file. 
    String name should be same.
```

[For Example, refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym6jX.png)

Comment: But this works only for static data not for dynamic values

Comment: yeah..that's a problem!! You have only one option: google translate api

Comment: You can try this..if it helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033583/how-to-get-hindi-keyboard-translate-into-hindi-text-programatically-in-android?rq=1]